# Java Script Mathmatic Equation

Tags: javascript, math, button

My javascript code isn't working because nothing's showing up when I click the button. Anybody know the solution? I already tried taking out the code and formatting the button to `alert(...)` and it worked, so now I'm stuck on whats going on with the math equations. I'm positive I didn't miss a bracket or punctuation though. Thanks for the feedback and help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project</title> 
        <style type="text"/css> 
            .inbox 
            { 
                width=30px; 
                text-align: right; 
                border: 2px solid black; 
            } 
            .align 
            { 
                text-align: right 
            } 
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function compute() {
                var a = form1.inputA.value;
                a = parseFloat(a);
                var b = form1.inputB.value;
                b = parseFloat(b);
                var c = form1.inputC.value;
                c = parseFloat(c);
                var e = a * 5.49;
                form1.sumA.value = e.toFixed(2);
            }
            function pageInit()
            {
                form1.inputA.focus();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="pageInit();">
        <form id="form1">
            <table border="2" >
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">Sample Order Form</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>item</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Totals</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input tabindex="1" class="inbox" type="text" id="inputA" />
                    </th>
                    <th>Apples</th>
                        <td>$5.49</td>
                        <th>
                            <input class="inbox" type="text" id="sumA" readonly="readonly" />
                        </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input tabindex="4" type="button" value="Compute" onclick="compute();" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so is it java or javascript?

Comment: you should re-format your question

Comment: You need to get the form element. Form1 has not been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <style>
        .inbox {
            width =30px;
            text-align: right;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        .align {
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function compute() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inputA").value;
            var e = a * 5.49;
            document.getElementById("sumA").value = e.toFixed(2);
        }
        function pageInit() {
            document.getElementById("inputA").focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="pageInit();">
    <form id="form1">
        <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Sample Order Form</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>item</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Totals</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input tabindex="1" class="inbox" type="text" id="inputA" />
                </th>
                <th>Apples</th>
                <td>$5.49</td>
                <th>
                    <input class="inbox" type="text" id="sumA" readonly="readonly" />
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input tabindex="4" type="button" value="Compute" onclick="compute();" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```